# rake runs dependents when file already exists

Tags: rake

I thought by doing

```
file 'myfile' => [ :some_task ]
```

the task would not be run since the file already exists, but when the file does exist the task runs. So is there a way to have the task not run when the file exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. what `:some_task` is.

`:some_task` is a Symbol, no String. It seems, `myfile` depends not on another file, but on a task.

If you have this situation:

```
require 'rake'

file 'myfile' => [ :some_task ] do |tsk|
  puts "Start #{tsk}" #some action  
end
task :some_task do |tsk|
  puts "Start #{tsk}" #some action
end
```

the question if `:some_task` is newer, makes no sense. It is a task to be executed always.

And if `myfile` has a prerequsite, that must be executed, then `myfile` will be created.